# Why can Python not recognize spark when I import?

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-import, importerror, pyspark

Python spits out an error when I try to import spark:

```
import pyspark.context
```

And the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#N>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyspark.context
ImportError: No module named pyspark.context
```

I have added the following to my `.bashrc` file, and I re-ran the terminal, too:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/<username>/Downloads/spark-1.4.0"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
```

The path to `SPARK_HOME` is the path preceding `/bin/pyspark`, and it contains the folder `python`, as it should.

My `PYTHONPATH` seems correct however, since I can import `numpy` and such.  What could be the problem?

Comment: May I ask why for the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try load pyspark programmatically:

```
import sys
try:
    sys.path.append("/Users/<username>/Downloads/spark-1.4.0/python/")
    from pyspark import context
    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
```

Comment: This works, of course, because you are manually adding it as a path.  This is a good idea, but it is not a permanent solution?    I thought that I could add the directory permanently by doing this:  `export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH`